# Weird results when using MATLAB's 'butter' function?

Tags: matlab, filter

I'm trying to learn some of the basic MATLAB filter design functions and have been experimenting with the 'butter' function. This function calculates the transfer function coefficients of a Buttersworth filter given a desired filter order and normalized cutoff frequency.

I have previous experiences with designing prototype filters and then modifying them, however, I'm having a difficult time understanding MATLAB's definition of normalized frequency.

I'm used to designing butter worth filters with a normalized frequency of 1 rad/s, yet MATLAB insists that the normalized frequency has something to do with a sample rate? I assumed the 'butter' function was used for designing analog filters?

Furthermore, when I plot the frequency response of the function, the cutoff frequency I specify (Wn parameter) never seems to correspond to the -3dB mark in the plots.

Any thoughts on these?

Comment: From the docs: "*butter returns the transfer function coefficients of an nth-order lowpass **digital** Butterworth filter*".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Jesus, apologies on my part for that.

Comment: adding `'s`' at the end of the function call makes `butter` create an analog filter. See the last example in [`doc butter`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html#buct21r)